# Is there a text editor that displays a file in more than one column

Tags: text-editor, multiple-columns

I have a wide screen and I would like to see the code I edit on multiple columns, like an article in a news paper. Ideally I would want the full screen filled with the content of the file I edit.

I am not interested in displaying multiple views of the same file in multiple windows, that's a different feature.

Comment: So how would this work, the next page would be on the other monitor ?

Comment: You should write an plugin for eclipse!

Comment: @nc3B, The next page would be on the next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Follow Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html) (Mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970292/emacs-multiple-columns-one-buffer)).

Otherwise, have you considered putting your widescreen in pivot-mode? It' quite useful both for coding and web-browsing! :)

Comment: Thanks!

I agree, except when I watch a movie...

A video driver that would split my physical screen into 3 virtual screens would perhaps make my day, I could stack the virtual screens the one on top of the other and my 1920x1280 physical screen would become a 640x3840 virtual desktop (moving the mouse would be a weird experience however).